# Debugger skips breakpoint (Visual Studio 2013 - .asm)

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, disassembly

as tittle says I cannot disassembly any code in Visual Studio 2013
I disabled "Just My Code" and "Step Over Properties and Operators" settings
solution is build properly

How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved

Project Properties -> Debugging -> Debuger Type change to Mixed